# Как заставить vue-instant выводить подсказки не соответствующие запросу?

Tags: vue.js

Юзаю прекрасный vue-instant и все в нем хорошо, только вот когда с back-end приходит массив "совпадений" vue-instant показывает только те, что строго соответствуют запросу.

То есть если я введу "Моск" - увижу "Москва", а если введу "Мокс" - то не увижу ничего, хотя в ответе от сервера придет "Москва" и я ее передеал через параметр "suggestions".

Как заставить выводить его все, что я ему даю?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <vue-instant
      suggestion-attribute="unrestricted_value"
      v-model="value"
      @input="changed"
      :show-autocomplete="true"
      :autofocus="false"
      :suggestions="suggestions"
      name="addrAutocomplete"
      placeholder="Начните вводить адрес"
      type="custom"
    ></vue-instant>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      value: "",
      suggestions: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changed: function() {
      var that = this;
      this.suggestions = [];

      if (this.value.length > 2) {
        this.$http.post("addresses", { name: this.value }).then(
          response => {
            response.data.forEach(function(a) {
              that.suggestions.push(a);
              console.log(that.suggestions); // - вот тут я вижу что данные попали в переменную, а vue-instant не хочет их выводить
            });
          },
          response => {
            console.log(response.body.message);
          }
        );
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Исправил. Надеюсь это поможет.

Comment: Чем докажите, что Вы все это сделали?)

Comment: Добавил доказательства)